# Problem to install react-reveal animation on terminal visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hello everybody i have a probem to install the react-reveal animation dependencie , each time when i put this command (npm install react-reveal --save) I have this problem, and i don't how i can resolve this problem, if a person had this problem or know how resolve this problem. can help me please thank you.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: portfolio-sebastien@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!   react-reveal@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/sebastienfirouzfar/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sebastienfirouzfar/.npm/_logs/2021-06-17T08_40_33_036Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 11):

This is because react-reveal has not been updated in about 4 years as you can see here https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal. Its dependencies are looking for react 15 or 16. You have react v17 so its throwing an error that it might not work with that version.

I can confirm that react-reveal works fine for me with react v17. But you will need to install react-reveal with this command:
`npm i react-reveal --legacy-peer-deps`.
Or if you already have the packages in your package.json then you can install everything without the errors by using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.

An alternative option is that you can ditch react-reveal and use [react-awesome-reveal](https://github.com/morellodev/react-awesome-reveal) instead. This package does similar fade and reveals for react but its API is slightly different and does not have all the advanced features of react-reveal. This would only be a replacement if you were using only the basic features of react-reveal.

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem probably because of `cache` or `npm` version so I will try to give you most feasible solution.

1-Delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files from your project.

2-Run `npm cache clean --force` in termial

3-Run `npm install`

4-Run `npm install react-reveal --save`

If it does not work you should try with different node version. You can use nvm (node version manager) which allows you to use and switch multiple node versions in your computer.

Comment: I found the problem, you must put this command in the terminal => npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Answer (score -1):

just for a quick solution you can use `npm i react-reveal --force`